# How is the git name determined when committing and pushing

Tags: git, push, commit

I committed in git and pushed, during push git is asking my user and password. Now, on github, my *computer account* user name is showing up. Why?

Specifically, `git config --system -l` returns "file not found".
`git config --global -l` has no user entry. `git config --local -l` has no user entry. Why is the user name not used I supplied during the push operation?

Comment: Note that when pushing, your username and password is -not really- asked by "git", but by ssh (or whatever is used to grant you access to the files of the repository). Once you get access to these files, git ignores the information you have entered to access these files.

Comment: Ah! Ok , this explains it. The information is not passed to git, basically. Never crossed my mind. If you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you push using git, two things happen:

1. First, you need to get write access to the files of the repository you are pushing to. Usually, this means ssh (not git) asks for your distant username and password.
2. Then, once the write access is granted, git can perform the push operation. It uses for this your local username set on your current machine using `git config --global user.name "My Name"`. Git ignores the username and password used in the previous step.

Answer (score 4):

Git uses `user.name` as your identifier - if it is not set, it defaults to your computer's username.

You should follow the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git) to fix this issue.

Short summary:

```
git config --global user.name "Billy Everyteen"
#Next command prints out to verify
git config --global user.name
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! It will definitely help avoiding my mistake of not configuring the git user (although I am myself reluctant to use --global as I have several git users in parallel). But commenter Boris hit the point with explaining that the granting process (e.g., ssh) is not related to the actual push.

Comment: @fruity Yep, SSH is used only as a way of accessing the `.git` directory. Git always is based around the file idea - ignoring conventions like SVN servers in favor of files, which can be processed through virtually any file request system, the most common being HTTP and SSH which both allow authentication.